# Facebook Unity SDK, how to force login using webview instead of FB App

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, webview, facebook-unity-sdk

By default, the FB Unity SDK will try to use the FB App to login if the user has it installed. Otherwise, it will fall back to using a HTML based popup to let the user login.

However the FB App only works with API 1.0 ("basic_info" permission). 
Will fail with "Invalid permissions" on "public_profile".

The webview dialog only works with API 2.0 ("public_profile" permission).
Will fail with "Invalid Scope: basic_info. Use public_profile".

The best fix would be to force the sdk to ignore the FB App and use webview to login all the time. Can this be done in Android?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Below link can solve your problem [Open webview diloag for facebook login](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367634/open-facebook-login-screen-in-personal-app-and-not-in-device-browser/43503005#43503005)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, try this

```
 openRequest.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO);
```

Or, if you use old fb sdk

```
authorize(activity, permissions, FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH, listener);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the latest SDK use [FB.Mobile.ShareDialogMode](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.Mobile.ShareDialogMode) to set the default behavior to webview.