# Facebook Unity SDK Login. How to always force in-game WebView login dialog?

Tags: android, ios, iphone, facebook-login, facebook-unity-sdk

Facebook SDK for Unity
Unity3d game
iOS and Android
Are there any ways to force Facebook always show in-app WebView login dialog, and do not leave my app (do not switch to Facebook App, or Safari)?

I already found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24253913/facebook-unity-sdk-how-to-force-login-using-webview-instead-of-fb-app), but it has no answer.

**Edit**
I found this in [Facebook docs](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#login) (click on question mark after p.2):

```
Android apps should use the default login behavior defined by the SDK, which may use the web-view Login dialog.  
On iOS, only kiosk apps may use a web-view Login dialog.
```

Our app is not a kiosk app, so on iOS we cannot use web-view based login.
If I understood right, on Android we should not alter the default behaviour of SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this in [Facebook docs](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#login) (click on question mark after p.2):

```
Android apps should use the default login behavior defined by the SDK, which may use the web-view Login dialog.  
On iOS, only kiosk apps may use a web-view Login dialog.
```

Our app is not a kiosk app, so on iOS we cannot use web-view based login.
If I understood right, on Android we should not alter the default behaviour of SDK.

Even if it is possible technically, we should not force such behaviour.