# Open facebook login screen in personal App and not in device browser

Tags: android, browser, facebook-login, in-app, twitter-login

When Facebook app are installed on device and i am not log in.
My own app opens facebook app when click on facebook login button.and if i am login on facebook app, my own app takes login details from facebook app and let me use login info. When i don't have facebook app installed on device, first time when i click on facebook login button in my own app it open facebook login page on default device browser and save my login credentials for next time.
when next time i try to login it directly fetch login info.

issue is when i open facebook website on default device browser (say chrome)explicitly. i directly get login to the account which i have loges in from my own app.

browser is caching login data, i want to stop that.

So i want to open login dialog contain webview for facebook login when click on facebook button.

I have taken button in xml like below

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/button_facebook_login"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

How can i achieve that?

Comment: I have also same question.

Answer (score 10):

You have to add below code in your activity it will work for you.

`LoginManager.getInstance().setLoginBehavior(LoginBehavior.WEB_VIEW_ONLY);`

OR

`facebookLoginButton.setLoginBehavior(LoginBehavior.WEB_VIEW_ONLY);`

For more info  please see below link

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/LoginBehavior/

Comment: `facebookLoginButton.setLoginBehavior(LoginBehavior.WEB_VIEW_ONLY);` worked for me in 2020 :)

Answer (score 0):

For FaceBook add this tag to your Manifest.XML file

```
<activity
            android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

and get `fb_login_protocol_scheme` value from the app dashboard in facebook developers

Comment: so why did you asked the question ??!!

Comment: I had this in my manifest already but this doesn't work for What i have asked. @Badr just by adding it not solving my problem.

Comment: are you sure you have completed all steps from facebook developers login documentation?

Comment: Yes i did, i can successfully login and logout with facebook. i just want login screen as webview dialogbox

Comment: Any solution to this? I'm also facing this issue. Facebook login opens in browser even though app is installed

Answer (score 0):

if your login facebook button open in browser update the sdk

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/upgrade-guide/

this is the last

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[8,9)'
```